# Tengo Problema Con El Error Atrribute En Varias Ocasiones

Tags: python, tkinter, chromedriver

Quiero comenzar a automatizar el ingreso de usuario y otras cosas en la web, estoy programando desde Sublime text y Chromedriver, siempre que intento correrlo al inicio me sale error de atributo

````
from selenium .webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
chrome_driver.get("https://starweb.solistica.com/StarWeb/hacceso.aspx")

usuario = chrome_driver.find_element_by_id("vUSRDSC")```

pero siempre que lo intento lanzar me sale este error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Proyectos\Selenium", line 9, in <module>
    usuario = chrome_driver.find_element_by_id("vUSRDSC")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'```

tengo ese problema en varias ocasiones que quiero programar, igualmente cuando quiero usar en otros textos el .get() me sale 

```from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()
cajaTexto = Entry(ventana).grid(row=0, column=0)

def click():
    texto = Label(ventana, text=f'se almaceno"cajaTexto.get()}").grid(row=1,column=0)

boton = Button(ventana, text="Ok", bg="yellow", command=click).grid(row=2,column=0)
ventana.mainloop()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el caso de selenium. Se esta mezclando el metodo `.find_element()` con el parametro `by.ID`

intenta:
`usuario = chrome_driver.find_element(by.ID,"vUSRDSC")`

La guia de selenium contiene mas posibles elementos en caso de requerirlos
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements

Comment: Agrego a lo que dice el compañero, estás usando sintáxis de versiones anteriores y lo más probable es que estés usando una versión nueva de Selenium.